# Conversion of boost::scoped_ptr to reference fails

Tags: c++, boost, smart-pointers

Can anyone explain why the conversion to the reference type fails in this example?
I want to use `boost::scoped_ptr`as a workaround for missing `std::unique_ptr`.

```
struct A{};

struct B
{
    B(boost::scoped_ptr<A>& a) { m_a.swap(a); }
    boost::scoped_ptr<A> m_a;
};

void f()
{
    B b(boost::scoped_ptr<A>(new A));
}
```

gcc fail with:

```
note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘boost::scoped_ptr<A>’ 
to ‘boost::scoped_ptr<A>&’
```

Design rationale (why use scoped_ptr in the first place):

- Don't want to use raw pointers because of exception safety (real-world scenario involves multiple objects to be passed)
- Don't want to use auto_ptr because of possible silent deallocation fails
- Can't use unique_ptr because still stuck with C++03
- Use of shared_ptr may be valid workaround but seems unclean because nothing is shared, really

Comment: You can use [Boost.Move](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/move.html) to write a C++03 compatible `unique_ptr`, for example, see [boost::interprocess::unique_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost/interprocess/unique_ptr.html).

Answer (score 4):

You can't bind non-const lvalue references to temporaries, as you do here

```
B b(boost::scoped_ptr<A>(new A));
```

You can fix that particular problem by passing an lvalue:

```
void f()
{   
    boost::scoped_ptr<A> a(new A);
    B b(a);
}
```